# C calling conventions in assembly (64 bit) - scanf

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit, printf, scanf

I have some assembly code that uses scanf and printf and I'm running into some problems. When both of these functions are used in the same code, the values in the registers seem to be lost. The program basically loads a number and prints it out. We run it using

```
nasm -f elf64 file.asm && gcc -o file file.o && ./file
```

on linux

Here's our code:

```
extern printf
extern scanf
section .data

  a db "set: ", 0
  b db "not set: ", 0
  reading db "Please enter a number: ", 0
  message db "\n", 0
  printsent db "%s", 10, 0
  printint db "%d", 10, 0
  printchar db "%c", 10, 0

  readInt db "%d", 0
  input db "%d", 0

section .text
    global main

main:

hatta: 
push rbp,
mov  rbp, rsp,
push rbx,
xor  rax, rax,
mov  rdi, printsent,
mov  rsi, reading
call  printf,
pop  rbx,

xor  rax, rax,
mov  rdi, readInt,
call  scanf,
mov  rbx, rdi

push rbx,
xor  rax, rax,
mov  rdi, printint,

mov  rsi, rbx,
call  printf,
pop  rbx,

pop  rbp,
ret
```

The odd thing is that if the line `mov rdi, printint,` is removed, we obtain the correct values. However, if we do the same thing with printsentence, we get a segmentation fault. Could anyone tell us the reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to say what OS you have, because calling conventions vary. Calling conventions are also differ between regular functions and variadic functions (such as printf), so be careful which info you read.

Comment: I suppose this is an exercise, since I don't think that coding such things in assembler still makes sense these days. The easiest way to find out how to do it is to write the correspondig C program, take your favorite compiler and compile it with `-S` or equivalent to have the assembler.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your `scanf` usage, possibly based on one false assumption: You seem to mean that `scanf` returns the loaded number in `rdi` and that no further argument is needed with format `"%d"`. In truth the number (if scanned successfully) is returned in the memory pointed to by the second argument. Thus, the following changes make the code work.

```
pop  rbx,                              |  ;delete
                                       =  
xor  rax, rax,                         =  xor  rax, rax,
mov  rdi, readInt,                     =  mov  rdi, readInt,
                                       >  mov  rsi, rsp
call  scanf,                           =  call  scanf,
mov  rbx, rdi                          |  pop  rbx,
```

Concerning *if the line mov rdi, printint, is removed, we obtain the correct values* - I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have the C flag here, there is no C code involved, but to your question:

As far as I remember the calling convention in Linux glibc x64 for `printf(format, argument)` is `format in rdi`, `argument in rsi`.

If you remove `mov  rdi, printsent,` then you are calling `printf(undefined,"Please enter a number: ")`. You did not provide a format argument in `rdi`, but `printf`
 doesn't know that and uses whatever is in `rdi` at that moment. Most likely an invalid memory address which thus invokes a `SIGSEGV`.

By default function calls in x86 are supposed to be non-destructive on the arguments, though this is not a requirement. Standard library functions generally are. They achieve this by pushing the arguments on to the stack and reload them when done.

As such when you call `scanf(readInt, ...)` it will restore the pointer to `readInt` which has the same contents as `printint` in `rdi` when it returns. As such removing the line `mov rdi, printint,` has no effect because `rdi` contains a valid pointer to the format you need.

Comment: "By default function calls in x86 are supposed to be non-destructive on the arguments" - this isn't true for 64bit x86 on either Win64 nor UN*X x86_64. Registers used for argument passing are scratch, and can be arbitrarily modified by the called function even if it doesn't actually take any arguments.

Comment: @FrankH.: moreover, it's not true in general, even for 32-bit calling conventions.  **The callee "owns" their stack args, and can freely clobber them.**  e.g. for making a tailcall with the same number of args, but different values: compilers *will* in practice do this.  Or just as scratch space, but compilers typically don't do that.  If you want to make another call with the same stack args, you have to store them again (unless inter-procedural optimization lets you know that the first callee chose not to clobber them.)